# Send Order Email to Custom email IDs when order by specific payment method

Tags: magento2.3, order-email

I have added one field in the configuration to add email IDS. When the order is placed by some payment method for example, "Cash on Delivery" I want to send New order email to those email IDs of the custom field.

I'm not understanding how to achieve this.

Please help me with this or give me some suggestions.

Comment: Add event "sales_order_place_after" check the payment method in observer & send email.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can achieve this requirement by few customizations**

**Step1:** Create a class which has setter and get method and using class you can pass an email to  `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity:getEmailCopyTo`.

**Code**

```
<?php


namespace DevAmitBera\OrderEmail\Model;


class OrderEmail
{
    private $extraOrderEmailId;

    public function set($email)
    {
        $this->extraOrderEmailId = $email;
    }
    public function get()
    {
        return $this->extraOrderEmailId;
    }
}
```

Step2: Create an observer on `email_order_set_template_vars_before` event and your custom email `$extraOrderEmailId` of `DevAmitBera\OrderEmail\Model\Order\OrderEmail`.

**Code**

```
<?php


namespace DevAmitBera\OrderEmail\Observer;


use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class EmailOrderSetTemplateVarsBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Ronin\ErpOrder\Model\OrderEmail
     */
    private $orderEmail;

    public function __construct(
        \Ronin\ErpOrder\Model\OrderEmail $orderEmail
    ){
        $this->orderEmail = $orderEmail;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $transportObject = $observer->getEvent()->getData('transportObject');
        if($transportObject->getData('order')){
            $order = $transportObject->getData('order');
            $payment = $order->getPayment();


           if($payment->getMethod() == 'cashondelivery'){
                $this->orderEmail->set(['dev.amitbera@gmail.com','amitberabca@gmail.com']);
           }

        }
    }
}
```

**Step3**: Create a plugin on `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity::getEmailCopyTo`

and then using after Plugin on the method `getEmailCopyTo`

and your  Custom email to order list

**Code**

```
<?php


namespace DevAmitBera\OrderEmail\Plugin\Order\Email\Container;


class OrderIdentity
{
    /**
     * @var \Ronin\ErpOrder\Model\OrderEmail
     */
    private $orderEmail;

    public function __construct(
        \Ronin\ErpOrder\Model\OrderEmail $orderEmail
    ){
        $this->orderEmail = $orderEmail;
    }

    public function afterGetEmailCopyTo(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity $subject,
        $result
    ){

        $additionalEmailId = $this->orderEmail->get();

        if(($additionalEmailId === null) || (!$additionalEmailId) || empty($additionalEmailId)){
            return $result;
        }

        if (!empty($result) && is_array($result)){

            foreach($additionalEmailId as $eachEmail){
               $result[] = (string) $eachEmail;     
            }

            return $result;
        }else{
            return [$additionalEmailId];
        }
    }

}
```

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="set_extra_params_to_order"
                  instance="DevAmitBera\OrderEmail\Observer\EmailOrderSetTemplateVarsBefore" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**di.xml** for plugin definition

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity">
        <plugin name="add_addition_class_to"
                type="DevAmitBera\OrderEmail\Plugin\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity"
                sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: It's not working. I think plugin is not calling

Comment: observer is also not calling. Can you please write complete?

Comment: <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
        <observer name="set_email_order" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\EmailOrderSetTemplateVarsBefore" />
    </event>
</config>

Comment: The answer is updated. Please check it

Comment: I have added same thing before updated your answer. etc/di.xml  but still not working

Comment: Is it support comma seperated emails?

Comment: I have checked it. It was not working when we use comma separated emails here.

if($payment->getMethod() == 'cashondelivery'){
                $this->orderEmail->set('dev.amitbera@gmail.com');
           }

Any solution please,

Comment: the answer is updated, Now, it  multiple email with command separate  will work